# VBA - Method "add" of Chart objects failed

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to create a function that will email a portion of a sheet, with the code below:

```
Function PictureToHTML(wbk, Namesheet, nameRange, imgFile)

    wbk.Activate
    Worksheets(Namesheet).Activate

    nameRange = "C7:C10"

    Set Plage = wbk.Worksheets(Namesheet).Range(nameRange)
    Plage.CopyPicture

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & imgFile

    Set newchart = wbk.Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.Width, Plage.Height)

    With newchart
        .Activate
        .Chart.parent.Border.LineStyle = 0
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export TempFilePath, "PNG"
    End With
    Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects(Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    Set Plage = Nothing

    PictureToHTML = "<br><B>" & Namesheet & ":</B><br>" _
                & "<img src='cid:" & imgFile & "'>"

End Function
```

I've temporarily hardcoded the range I want to cut (even though it shouldn't be an issue...), and I get the error on this line:

```
Set newchart = wbk.Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.Width, Plage.Height)
```

Full error:

> Run-time error'-2147417878 (80010108)':
>       Method 'Add' of object 'ChartObjects' failed

Could anyone tell me where my mistake is?
Updated code:

```
Function PictureToHTML(wbk, Namesheet, nameRange, imgFile)

    Dim WeightsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newChart As ChartObject
    wbk.Activate

    Set WeightsSheet = wbk.Worksheets(Namesheet)

    Set Plage = wbk.Worksheets(Namesheet).Range(nameRange)
    Plage.CopyPicture

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & imgFile
    Set newChart = WeightsSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.Width, Plage.Height)

    With newChart
        .Activate
        .Chart.parent.Border.LineStyle = 0
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export TempFilePath, "PNG"
    End With
    WeightsSheet.ChartObjects(WeightsSheet.ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    Set Plage = Nothing

    PictureToHTML = "<br><B>" & Namesheet & ":</B><br>" _
                & "<img src='cid:" & imgFile & "'>"

End Function
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @RikSportel updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are not explicitly declared. Although it should not be a problem here, as the `newChart` should be considered `Variant`, try to write `Dim newChart as ChartObject` on the line before `wbk.Activate`.

Then calling separately something as small as this one:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim newChart As ChartObject
    Set newChart = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 100, 100)
End Sub
```

And then start adding `Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.Width, Plage.Height` instead of the hardcoded arguments (100). Then add `wbk.Worksheets(Namesheet)` as well and see whether it works.

---

Not declaring variables is really a bad practice. This works, if you declare all. In this specific small example, the problem is the `nameRange` variable:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print PictureToHTML(ThisWorkbook, "Sheet1", Range("A1:E20"), "probably.png")
End Sub

Function PictureToHTML(wbk As Workbook, Namesheet As String, _
                        nameRange As Range, imgFile As String) As String

    Dim WeightsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newChart As ChartObject
    Dim Plage As Range
    Dim tempFilePath As String

    Set WeightsSheet = wbk.Worksheets(Namesheet)

    Set Plage = wbk.Worksheets(Namesheet).Range(nameRange.Address)
    Plage.CopyPicture

    tempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & imgFile
    Set newChart = WeightsSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
                        Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.Width, Plage.Height)

    With newChart
        .Chart.Parent.Border.LineStyle = 0
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export tempFilePath, "PNG"
    End With

    WeightsSheet.ChartObjects(WeightsSheet.ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    PictureToHTML = "<br><B>" & Namesheet & ":</B><br>" & "<img src='cid:" & imgFile & "'>"

End Function
```

---

As a next step, consider reading the documentation for Option Explicit:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement
- [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: It seems like `wbk.Worksheets(1)` is the solution... why doesn't my version of this seem to work? My value for namesheet is "Weights", which is a sheet that exists in my workbook.

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois - no idea. In general, the code lacks explicit declarations of variables and uses a lot of Active and Select, thus probably the error is somewhere there... See the 2 links in the answer, they are quite useful.

Comment: I added some updated code where I adhere to the idea of explicitly declaring variables. It seems like I still get the same error, could it be because my workbook uses Activate? How would I replace that in the context of my function?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois - the error is from the range variable `nameRange`. See the code in the answer.